# Facing trouble with visual studio 2017 RC reinstallation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

```
[33fc:0018][2017-03-06T22:09:06] Error 0x80004003: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.InstanceRepository.GetInstance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.<GetInstances>d__27.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Just at the start of the installation it breaks and i get the above lines as the log file. How do I reinstall?

Comment: VS2017 will be released tomorrow, wait one day

Comment: The final didn't install either. The installer was broken and the below procedure fixed that.

Answer (score -1):

### The rigorous uninstall procedure is as follows

If you, like me, are stuck trying to upgrade Visual Studio 2017, then you may only get unblocked by removing everything and starting afresh. Since Visual Studio 2017 is still in Release Candidate and not final, this is something we may have to deal with from time to time.

But when the "uninstall" button in the ui fails, you may end up stuck. In that case, you'll be happy to find:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\installcleanup.exe
```

Which will perform the same actions as the good old `vssetup.exe /uninstall /force`. If that doesn't get you unstuck, there is an even more forceful way:

Delete everything under:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages
%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0*
%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0*
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0*
```

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-2017-force-uninstall/

Comment: Why the - 1?likely the RTW won't install either, as it will try to upgrade the existing installation. Which is clearly broken.